# how to create dynamic TableCells for Tableview in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

What I want to achieve is something like this. its kind of Facebook or twitter functionality where you have a tableview in which you have a Thread and the thread contains different number of articles. the number of articles varies in each row. So basically Its like i'm sending a post on facebook and people respond to that post and those posts are added under that particular Thread(I'm just concern about the How to display it every thing else is been taken care).here is the picture[image]

I know how to create cell and all but I don't know how to set its size dynamically. any tutorial or any piece of advise to achieve this??

Any Help is appreciated..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help you. I am sending you my code, I am using a Custom Cell , which having an Emial on first index, PhoneNumber on second index and Address on third index (in your case Article). I am dynamically changing the height of Address label in CellForRowAtIndexPath ,,, and also cell height in heightForRowAtIndexPath mehthod. Here is my code.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *identifier = @"FeedCell";
    FeedDetailCell *cell = (FeedDetailCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = (FeedDetailCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FeedDetail" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                cell.nameLabel.text = @"Telephone";
                [cell.detailLabel setText:[_feedDictionary valueForKey:@"mobile"]];
            }
            else {
                cell.nameLabel.text = @"Mobile";
                [cell.detailLabel setText:[_feedDictionary valueForKey:@"iPhone"]];
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.nameLabel.text = @"E-mail";
            [cell.detailLabel setText:[_feedDictionary valueForKey:@"Email"]];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.nameLabel.text = @"address";
            [cell.detailLabel setText:[_feedDictionary valueForKey:@"address"]];
            CGSize size = [[_feedDictionary valueForKey:@"address"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200.0, 400.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            CGRect frm = cell.detailLabel.frame;
            frm.size.height = size.height;
            [cell.detailLabel setFrame:frm];
        default:
           break;
    }
    return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        NSString *address = [_feedDictionary valueForKey:@"address"];
        CGSize recommendedSize = [address sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, INT_MAX)];
        return 44 + recommendedSize.height;
    }
    else {
        return 44;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for dynamic cell height

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
```

you can use switch cases and check **indexPath.row** and **indexPath.section** to return the required height

Comment: Thanks for the help but can you please explain it in bit detail or can you please suggest a tutorial of example that I can follow.

Answer (score 1):

take a custom UITableViewCell ,
in .h file

```
 @interface PartnerCell : UITableViewCell {
        UILabel  *user_name,*lbldate,*lbldesc;
        LoadImage *img_trade;
        UIImageView *partnerimage;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *user_name,*lbldate,*lbldesc;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) LoadImage *img_trade;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *partnerimage;
    @end
```

in .m file,

#import "PartnerCell.h"

```
@implementation PartnerCell
@synthesize user_name,lbldate,lbldesc;
@synthesize img_trade,partnerimage;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {   

        [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        user_name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75,8,200,15)];
        [user_name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        user_name.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:15];
        [user_name setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:70/255.00f green:70/255.00f blue:70/255.00f alpha:1.0]];
        [self addSubview:user_name];

        lbldate = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75,28,200,15)];
        [lbldate setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        lbldate.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
        [lbldate setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [self addSubview:lbldate];


        lbldesc = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75,45,170,35)];
        [lbldesc setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        lbldesc.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        lbldesc.numberOfLines = 2;
        [lbldesc setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
        [self addSubview:lbldesc];


        img_trade = [[LoadImage alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 5, 54, 55)];
        img_trade.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self addSubview:img_trade];



    }
    return self;
}
```

in main table view class write this code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[Partarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] valueForKey:@"part_id"]];
cell = (PartnerCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell=nil;
if (cell == nil)
{   
    cell = [[PartnerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:[Partarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.user_name.frame=CGRectMake(75,8,340,15);
    cell.lbldate.frame=CGRectMake(75,28,340,15);
    cell.lbldesc.frame=CGRectMake(75,45,340,35);


    cell.user_name.text = @"user name";
    cell.lbldate.text = @"date";
    cell.lbldesc.text = @"description";



}
    return cell;
}
```

take condition and add  number of objects based on that condition.